# i want to add a condition to (for) loop

Tags: batch-file

in this code it converts pcap files to csv but i want to add a size condition

in order to convert pacp file greater than or equal 1 megabyte

here is the code

```
:START

set /a Old = 0
set /a New = 0
echo Counting files in folder..
for /f "tokens=*" %%P IN ('dir "C:\Users\..." /A /b') do (set /a Old += 1)
set Old
:: delay 120 sec
echo Delaying 120 seconds... (drop new file in)
timeout /T 9
echo Checking for new files..
for /f "tokens=*" %%P IN ('dir "C:\Users\S..." /A /b') do (set /a New += 1)
set New
goto COMPARE

:COMPARE
echo Comparing number of files
if %New% GEQ %Old% goto NEWF
goto OLDF

:NEWF
echo 
**for %%F in (*.pcap) do if not exist "%%~dpnF.csv" tshark -r "%%F" -T fields -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e data.text -e  tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack -e tcp.analysis.out_of_order -e tcp.analysis.retransmission -e tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission -e tcp.analysis.spurious_retransmission -e tcp.analysis.zero_window -e tcp.stream -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e data.len > "%%~dpnF.csv"**

goto START

:OLDF
echo No New Files.
echo Restarting
goto START
```

i want to add condition in for loop in echo after NEWF

any help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%F in (*.pcap) do IF %%~zF GTR 1048576 if not exist "%%~dpnF.csv" tshark -r "%%F" -T fields -E header=y -E separator=, -E quote=d -e frame.number -e frame.time -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e data.text -e  tcp.analysis.duplicate_ack -e tcp.analysis.out_of_order -e tcp.analysis.retransmission -e tcp.analysis.fast_retransmission -e tcp.analysis.spurious_retransmission -e tcp.analysis.zero_window -e tcp.stream -e tcp.srcport -e tcp.dstport -e data.len > "%%~dpnF.csv"**
```

should execute the rest of the line only if the size of the file in `%%F` is greater than 1Mb